# Passing the current class trouble

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parameter-passing

I thought I know the fundamentals of python, but this problem seems to prove that wrong.

Problem is, when I pass a class to a function, that function will not recognize the class that I passed, but instead just recognize that parent class.

This is the class.

```
from tkinter import *

from one_sample_t_test_dialog import One_T_Test_Dialog
from about_us_dialog import About_Us_Dialog


class Gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, background="white")
        self._master = master
        # Main Window
        frame = Frame(master, width = 800, height = 600)
        self._master.title("Statistics Program")        

        # Menus
        menu = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)
        # --Tests
        test_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label = "Tests", menu = test_menu)
        # ----T-Tests
        t_test_menu = Menu(test_menu)
        test_menu.add_cascade(label = "T-Tests", menu = t_test_menu)
        t_test_menu.add_command(label="One Sample t-test", command = self.one_sample_t_test)
        t_test_menu.add_command(label="Two Sample t-test", command = self.two_sample_t_test)
        t_test_menu.add_command(label="Paired t-test", command = self.about_us)
        # --Help
        help_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = help_menu)
        help_menu.add_command(label="About Us", command = self.about_us)

        # Toolbar
        # --t-test
        toolbar = Frame(master)
        l = Label(toolbar, text="Mean Comparison:")
        l.pack(side=LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        b=Button(toolbar, text = "One Sample t-test", command=self.one_sample_t_test)
        b.pack(side=LEFT)
        b=Button(toolbar, text = "Two Sample t-test", command=self.two_sample_t_test)
        b.pack(side=LEFT)
        b=Button(toolbar, text = "Paired t-test", command=self.two_sample_t_test)
        b.pack(side=LEFT)
        # --anova
        l=Label(toolbar, text="ANOVA:")
        l.pack(side=LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        b=Button(toolbar, text = "One Way Anova", command=self.two_sample_t_test)
        b.pack(side=LEFT)
        # --Multiple-comparison Tests
        toolbar_02 = Frame(master)
        l=Label(toolbar_02, text="Multiple Mean Comparison:")
        l.pack(side=LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        b=Button(toolbar_02, text = "Tukey", command=self.two_sample_t_test)
        b.pack(side=LEFT)
        b=Button(toolbar_02, text = "Bonferroni", command=self.two_sample_t_test)
        b.pack(side=LEFT)

        toolbar.pack(fill=BOTH)
        toolbar_02.pack(fill=BOTH)

        # Spreadsheet.
        self.canvas = canvas =  Canvas(self._master)
        self.canvas_frame = canvas_frame = Frame(canvas)
        # Scrollbars
        vbar=Scrollbar(self._master,orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        hbar=Scrollbar(self._master,orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        # Further configuration
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set, xscrollcommand=hbar.set)
        # Initialize scrollbars
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill="both")
        canvas.create_window((4,4), window=canvas_frame, anchor="nw")
        canvas_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
        self.grid()
        #canvas_frame.pack()

        self._master.geometry("800x600+50+50")
        #self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def get_master(self):
        return self._master

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def about_us(self):
        d = About_Us_Dialog(self._master)
        root.wait_window(d.parent)

    def grid(self):
        """
        Make the grid here.
        """
        grid_frame = self.canvas_frame
        self.entry = []
        for i in range(40):
            self.entry.append([])

        for i in range(len(self.entry)):
            for j in range(80):
                self.entry[i].append(Entry(grid_frame, width=10))
                self.entry[i][j].grid(row=j, column=i)

        # grid_frame.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

    def one_sample_t_test(self):        
        d = One_T_Test_Dialog(self)
        value = self._master.wait_window(d.parent)

        # Check if an error occured.
        result = None # We will store the result here.
        if value is None:
            return
        else:
            # perform the t-test here.
            pass

        # If we made it at this point, there's no error and 
        # the result have been acquired. We can now display
        # the result.

    def two_sample_t_test(self):
        # Testing Ground
        #print(self.get_variables())
        #print(self.get_values(3))
        pass

    def get_variables(self):
        """
        This method will return a dictionary of variable names and their corresponding
        index, that is located in index zero of the double array. For instance, 
        self.entry[3][0] is a variable name, so is self.entry[5][0], and so on.
        """
        variable_name_dict = {}
        for i in range(len(self.entry)):
            temp = self.entry[i][0].get()
            if temp is not "":
                variable_name_dict[i] = temp

        return variable_name_dict

    def get_values(self, variable_index):
        """
        This method will return a list of values that is located under the variable.
        Use this in conjunction with get_variables().
        """
        values = []
        if self.entry[variable_index][0] is not "": # Make sure that it's not empty.
            for v in self.entry[variable_index]:
                if v.get() is not "":
                    values.append(v.get())
        # Since the first cell is in the column is always a variable name, we can 
        # pop the first element.
        values.pop(0)
        return values

root = Tk()
app = Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the other class, with a method being called by the class above. the class above pass itself as an argument.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

import dialog 

class One_T_Test_Dialog(dialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, gui):
        master = gui.get_master()
        # Entry Labels.
        Label(master, text="Mean:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Standard Deviation:").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="Sample Size:").grid(row=2)
        Label(master, text="Sample Size:").grid(row=3)
        Label(master, text="Test Value:").grid(row=4)

        # Data entry class members.
        # The for loop initialize the list as an entry list.
        num_of_entry = 5
        self.entry = [] #entry list
        for i in range(num_of_entry):
            self.entry.append(Entry(master))

        # Data entry location initialization.
        for i in range(num_of_entry):
            self.entry[i].grid(row=i,column=1)

        # Or, the user can just select a mean from the drop down list and
        # enteryt the test value.
        Label(master, text="Select Values Instead:").grid(column = 0, row=5)
        self.dropdown_val = StringVar(master)
        # initial value
        self.dropdown_val.set('Select a values.')
        choices = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow','white', 'magenta']
        option = OptionMenu(master, self.dropdown_val, *choices).grid(column = 1, row=5)
        button = Button(master, text="check value slected").grid(column=1, row=6)

        # Further initialization.
        # --At the Test Value, or null hypothesis, we want to have a default
        # value. Assuming this is a 151/252 level course, the default value
        # is always 0.
        self.entry[4].insert(0, "0")

        return self.entry[0] # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        # Collect the data first.
        data_list = []
        for e in self.entry:
            data_list.append(e.get())

        # Validate
        for d in data_list:
            # Make sure it's not empty.
            # Make sure the value is float.
            empty_flag = False
            not_float_flag = False

            if len(d) == 0:
                empty_flag = True

            if empty_flag is False:
                try:
                    float(d)
                except ValueError:
                    not_float_flag = True

            if empty_flag is True or not_float_flag is True:
                # Report an input error.
                if empty_flag is True and not_float_flag is False:
                    messagebox.showerror("INPUT ERROR", "There's an empty input box.")
                elif not_float_flag is True and empty_flag is False:
                    messagebox.showerror("INPUT ERROR", "Check your input. Make sure its a number.")
                elif not_float_flag is True and empty_flag is True:
                    messagebox.showerror("INPUT ERROR", "There's an empty input box and non-numerical input.")
                return None

        # If everything went well, convert the validated data.
        for i in range(len(data_list)):
            data_list[i] = float(data_list[i])

        return data_list
```

The problem is the line 
    master = gui.get_master()
in the second class gives an error because
    AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'get_master'
Frame being the parent of the class Gui.

Comment: Right now your code is a syntax error, could you please fix it?

Comment: Also you can't pass a class to a function in it's definition, it will just become a variable name in the parameters of the function, it won't have anything to do with the class. What are you tring to do?

Comment: @jamylak it's suppose to be a pseudo code... I only showed the essentials to elaborate the problem.

Comment: @jamylak I'm trying to pass the class foo to the outside function. Ho do I do that if this is wrong??

Comment: In addition to what @jamylak pointed out; `self` is not the class, `self` is the instance. If you can tell us the _actual problem you are trying to solve_, that will help.

Comment: What you are saying is simply false. Provide an example that shows the actual problem or explain correctly what you want to say.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I'm trying to pass the current class so the other function can retrieve what it wants to retrieve from the current class' parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current class" and "the parent class"?  You example contains only one class, and you never call your `outside_foo` function anyway.

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry about that. Well, I inserted my whole problem now.

Comment: The example you posted is large and contains lots of irrelevant code.  Please try to produce a simple, self-contained, runnable example that demonstrates the problem you are having.  I note that your second code snipper imports a module `dialog` that you don't describe.  It's possible the problem lies there.